# Android findViewById returns null, but only for my custom view

Tags: android

I have an activity with a button on it:

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/some_id" />
```

and I can find it just fine from the activity's source:

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.some_id); // returns the button
```

but if I switch the button for a custom control:

```
<FancyButton
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/some_id" />
```

then I start getting null instead:

```
fancyButton = (FancyButton)findViewById(R.id.some_id); // returns null
```

Fancy button is really just an empty view at the moment, so I'm not sure what could cause it to fail like this:

```
public FancyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);

    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fancy_button, this, true);
}
```

I definitely missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to forward the attributes parameter to the base constructor. Since the id is an attribute, it ended up dropped on the floor instead of set.

Wrong:

```
public FancyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
```

Right:

```
public FancyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
```

Turning on "unused parameter" warnings would have caught this faster.